# SQL geometry::STGeomFromText throwing error and stopping job

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Folks,

Got an odd one for you.

I've got a stored procedure I use to parse some tabular data to create proper SQL geometry objects.

The SP makes use of the function MakeValid().

In my case I have found some objects that fail the test. These do not break the stored procedure however. The Stored procedure is happy to run and simply show the error in the results.

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 257 A .NET Framework error occurred
>   during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
>   System.FormatException: 24306:

However when I execute this SP in a scheduled job, the first time it encounters one of these exceptions the job fails and the SP stops running.

I'm actually not sure what to do here. I've tried a TRY..CATCH block but this doesn't stop the error being raised and the job exits anyway.

So while it's a MakeValid function that's raising the error I would imagine an SP that encounters a function error would cause the same issue.

Any thoughts how I might handle this? BTW I have no control over the input quality other than to flag the errors and then go back and repair them. I'd still like the rest of the valid records to be processed though.

Here's the operable section of code.

```
SET @GEOM = geometry::STGeomFromText(@GEOMWKT, 4326)

IF @GEOM.STIsValid() = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @GEOM = @GEOM.MakeValid()
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        Print 'Error here'
    END CATCH
END
```

Here is an example of an invalid geometry that throws an error.

```
SET @GEOM = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-121.895652 37.37225, -121.895652 37.37225)', 4326)
```

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: You're checking `@GEOM` but doing operations against `@VALGEOM`. Is that your intention?

Comment: Nuts. That would have been the simplest solution. Can you provide a simple WKT that produces this error?

Comment: Ben here is an example of the syntax that throws an error.
SET @GEOM = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-121.895652 37.37225, -121.895652 37.37225)', 4326) 
Also added to original question.

Comment: The two endpoints of that line are the same point. Therefore, I don't think it's valid WKT. That is, nothing can be done to *make* it valid. What is your expectation? That MakeValid return a NULL value?

Comment: In other news, I have a SQL 2014 instance on my laptop and both the geometry instance you've specified and calling `MakeValid()` on it work for me. So this might just be a case of "spatial was v1 in 2008; caveat emptor".

Comment: Thanks for continuing to look at this. The issue is not that the geometry is invalid. I know it is. However if I run my code as in SSMS the code will happily run through the thousands of WKT records, register the odd failure and continue on. My issue is when I set this up as a SP and run it as a job. In this case the first failed MakeValid call stops the job. I can't, for the life of me, build a handler for this mode of failure that works.  So perhaps its not the MakeValid > fail that's the problem it's how the TRY..CATCH has been implemented?

Comment: Ah! My suggestion would be, since the spatial stuff is all implemented in CLR anyways, to write a wrapper *in* CLR that does the try/catch there and just returns NULL if it can't do it. I'll take a swing later tonight/tomorrow (assuming you don't beat me to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is the answer that I'm going with but significant credit goes to Ben Thul for the CLR which achieves the same result using a different method.

The realisation is more correctly understanding the question. I made two mistakes. The first was not realising the error I was trying to catch was outside the TRY..CATCH block. The second was believing I needed to try and validate the WKB expression of the geometry. In fact, the following method allows the validation of the WKT *before* attempting to create a WKB. The following method identifies the **invalid WKT**, sets a TRUE/FALSE condition. With the WKT validated a valid WKB can be safely created.

Once I understood the question asking the right question turned up the solution here.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66642/detecting-invalid-wkt-in-text-column-in-sql-server

I have adapted the code to suit my implementation.

```
/*REVISED CODE*/

DECLARE @valid bit
DECLARE @GEOMWKT varchar(max)
DECLARE @GEOM geometry

Set @GEOMWKT = 'LINESTRING(-121.895652 37.37225, -121.895652 37.37225)'-- Test faulty value
Set @valid = 1
--Test WKT
BEGIN TRY                                                           --The is the test here. 
    SET @valid = geometry::STGeomFromText(@GEOMWKT, 4326).STIsValid()--We don't try to 
 END TRY                                                            --MakeValid(). No point.
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @valid = 0
END CATCH
--Now that we know whether the WKT will pass or fail we can operate in a known 
--state and avoid raising an error
IF @valid = 1
BEGIN
    SET @GEOM = geometry::STGeomFromText(@GEOMWKT, 4326)--Safely create a valid WKB
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
   SET @GEOM = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT EMPTY', 4326)-- Set geometry to empty on fail
   Print 'Geometry Fail'
END
```

Comment: Super useful solution to your problem - I adapted to my own issue quite easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time validating that this will work for you (i.e. my local instance is *too good* at calling `MakeValid()`), but this might just work for you.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlGeometry TryMakeValid_geometry(SqlGeometry g)
    {
        SqlGeometry r;
        try
        {
            r = g.MakeValid();

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            r = SqlGeometry.Null;
        }
        return r;
    }

    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlGeometry TryParseWKT_geometry(SqlString wkt)
    {
        SqlGeometry r;
        try
        {
            r = SqlGeometry.Parse(wkt).MakeValid();
        }
        catch
        {
            r = SqlGeometry.Null;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Deploy this CLR to your database and call the function with your geometry instance. It should return NULL if the call to `MakeValid()` fails.

Comment: Ben I got this compiled and deployed. Small tip for anyone following along In Visual Studio you need to compile for .Net 2.0 for SQL 2008. Later .Net versions support later versions of SQL. As a result it seems I have completely mis-characterised the problem. The error is thrown by the line
SET @GEOM = geometry::STGeomFromText(
not the MakeValid(). So like so many other threads I've read I'm actually not catching the error at all the way I have my code constructed. I'll rework the code and see if simply writing it correctly will fix the problem!

Comment: It's thrown by the what?! I'm on pins and needles!

Comment: Thrown by the line 
SET @GEOM = geometry::STGeomFromText(@GEOMWKT, 4326).
If you pass this line an invalid geometry this throws the error.
However see my next comment.

Comment: OK this is getting frustrating. On this page
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933890.aspx
This is a quote in the Remarks section
"SQL Server produces only valid geometry instances, **but allows for the storage and retrieval of invalid instances**. A valid instance representing the same point set of any invalid instance can be retrieved using the MakeValid() method."
However this appears to be supported on SQL 2012. As you've suggested Ben with 2008 I may be SOL.

Comment: Ah! I understand your frustration. I've edited the code above to add another CLR UDF that does tries the *parsing*. If either the parsing or the call to `MakeValid()` fail, it returns a NULL value but doesn't error out. This one I *can* test; I passed `KITTEN` as my WKT and it indeed returns a NULL value (whereas passing that to `STGeomFromText()` does throw a CLR error).